# Not able to set hidden property

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use this `canUpdate` flag to switch the hidden property in the html. I can see in the console that the `canUpdate` value is false so I am not sure what else I will need to do.

HTML

```
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" [disabled]="updateVersionItemsInProgress">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateItems()" [disabled]="updateVersionItemsInProgress" [hidden]="!canUpdate">Update</button>
    </div>
```

Component

```
validateUpdateItems(): void {
    console.log('validateUpdateItems')
    let versionKeys = this.items.map(i => i.VersionKey);
    this.templatesManagementService.ValidateUpdateToNewVersionRelatedTemplates(versionKeys)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.IsValid) {
                this.canUpdate = true;
                console.log(this.canUpdate)
            } else {
                
                this.canUpdate = false;
                console.log(this.canUpdate)
                this.updateVersionItemsWarningMessage = response.Message;
                if (response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.length > 0) {
                    let strupdateVersionItemsWarningMessageDetails = Enumerable
                        .From(response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates)
                        .Select(unpublishedRelatedTemplate => unpublishedRelatedTemplate.RelatedTemplateId + " (" + unpublishedRelatedTemplate.TemplateId + ")")
                        .ToArray();
                    this.updateVersionItemsWarningMessageDetails = strupdateVersionItemsWarningMessageDetails;
                }
            }
            this.updateVersionItemsInProgress = false;
        })
        .fail(e => {
            this.failedAction(e);
            $('#update-NewVersion-templates-modal').modal('hide');
            this.updateVersionItemsInProgress = false;
        });
}
```

Console

[image]

runtime displays hidden
[image]

Comment: from my understanding, you may want to use `*ngIf` instead of `[hidden]`

Comment: You mean something like this <div *ngIf="canUpdate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem you says false it means show it, u need to `!canUpdate` if you want to hide while false

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateItems()" [disabled]="updateVersionItemsInProgress" [hidden]="!canUpdate">Update</button>
```

if not work your css may overwritten then put in style.css

```
button[hidden] { display: none; } /* add !important if still not working*/
```

Comment: even using !canUpdate it still displays the button html display just hidden

Comment: Can you try this to add style.css     `button[hidden] { display: none; }` @Jefferson

Answer (score 1):

[hidden] is a property which hides the element/button in your case if `[hidden]="true"`

Since you are receiving false in your console, which means [hidden] is getting set to false and that's the reason the button is not getting hidden.